# Update Table From Select Statement Sql Query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, select, sum

I have three tables, one holds a list of available products with relevant details such as  product price, the other holds orders and the last holds specific order details including the items purchased in an order.

I am trying to create a query to calculate the total price of an order by linking the two of the tables with an inner join and then updating the order table with the value. The code I have written contains syntax errors, being a novice I have probably made an obvious mistake but any help would be appreciated.

```
 "SELECT Sum(ProductTable.prodPrice) AS Total, OrderDetailTable.orderID " +
             "FROM ProductTable INNER JOIN OrderDetailTable " +
             "ON ProductTable.prodID = OrderDetailTable.prodID " +
             "GROUP BY OrderDetailTable.orderID " +
             "HAVING OrderDetailTable.orderID = ? " +
             "UPDATE OrderTable " +
             "SET " +
             "totalPrice = Total "  +
             "WHERE OrderTable.orderID = ? ";
```

I am using Access.
I also forgot to mention that the ? is represented using a Dataview parameter

```
        pc.Add(new Parameter("?", TypeCode.Int32, basketId.ToString()));
```

EDIT: Using PaqoGomez's suggestion to declare Total as a value I now get the error : Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '0WHERE OrderTable.orderID = ?'.

Comment: Updates from queries tend to be vendor specific. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Access

Comment: Sorry but pretty much any attempt at this will result in "Operation Must use Updatable Query" You might try using a query instead and join to that.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?  It looks like a simple string concatenation spacing issue from here.  Please consider upvoting, marking answers or commenting on those answers that help you.

Answer (score 3):

Comment made before OP described this as MS Access: 
Haven't tried this but you had the Select and update the wrong way round. This should be quite close. Its been a while for me but you may need to change the FROM clause to reference the table you are updating and INNER JOIN the sub-select instead of the WHERE clause.

```
"UPDATE OrderTable " +
"SET totalPrice = Sum(ProductTable.prodPrice)" +
"FROM (" +
    "SELECT OrderDetailTable.orderID, Sum(ProductTable.prodPrice)" +
    "FROM ProductTable INNER JOIN OrderDetailTable " +
    "ON ProductTable.prodID = OrderDetailTable.prodID " +
    "GROUP BY OrderDetailTable.orderID " +
    ") x" +
"WHERE x.orderID = OrderTable.OrderId"
```

---

UPDATE :

Based on OPs update regarding MS Access you can do an update with a sub-query, but I think it depends on the version of MS Access you are using and how you do it. Posts below seem to indicate it's quite problematic:

[SQL Subqueries (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192664%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[How do I perform update query with subquery in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375207/how-do-i-perform-update-query-with-subquery-in-access)

[Can It Be Done - Access 2007 SQL Update Query Using a Subquery?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9a7bf72e-0cfd-424d-911b-5e820c65f5df/can-it-be-done-access-2007-sql-update-query-using-a-subquery?forum=accessdev)

Comment: This syntax isn't at all close for Access. It does something like `UPDATE T1 JOIN t2 SET t1.field = t2.field`

Comment: @ConradFrix agreed. OP updated the post to say it was from MS Access after I had posted. I've updated the post to try to add some assistance.

Comment: Looks like OP disappeared. Great answer, I'll give you a +1

Answer (score 0):

By declaring a variable you can save the total value so that you can use it in the later update.

```
declare @Total int;
SELECT @Total = Sum(ProductTable.prodPrice)
//...
"SET " +
"totalPrice = @Total "
```

You dont mention which database platform you are using, I'm assuming MSSQL, other platforms would require a slightly different syntax.

You might also be interested to know that if you use the `@` symbol you can have a multiline string.  This would allow you to avoid the concatenation that you are doing. eg.

```
var sql = @"some
              sql
            string"
```

Comment: Oh sorry about that it is Access.

Comment: @user3495336, that syntax will work for Access as well.  Please be sure to upvote and mark as answer when a post is helpful! Thanks

Comment: @user3495336, did you find an answer?

Comment: Sorry again for the late reply, the exact syntax that you provided was not compatible with my project but I adjusted it in order to declare Total as an integer and then use it to set totalPrice equal to it. I am still getting syntax errors when trying to update the database (missing operator).

Comment: @user3495336, missing operator? I dont follow, can you update the question with the error?  Or perhaps you should accept an answer here and create a new question?