# Update Table with a Value in a Corresponding Field to the Minimum value of Another Field

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have seen several posts that address how to use an aggregate function in an Update query. However, these posts vary enough from my issue that I cannot come up with a solution.

I have a temp table called tblDistanceCalc (See below) The field ClosestCity is actually not the closest city to the origin, but instead it contains many other cities (of my choosing) in the state. Then the distance from the Origin to the "ClosestCity" is in the Distance Field. The Region field represents the Region of the closest city.

```
tblDistanceCalc
Origin \\ ClosestCity \\ Distance \\ Region
```

Then I have another table which I am looking to update called tblnewbid. It has fields for Origin, Destination. And my code creates fields for O_CityRegion and D_CityRegion before carrying on with the rest.

```
tblnewbid
Origin \\ Destination \\ O_CityRegion \\ D_CityRegion
```

I need code that will match the Origin in tblnewbid to the Origin in tblDistanceCalc, find the minimum distance for that Origin in the Distance field, and return the Region in the corresponding field to the Minimum Distance.

I was going to simplify my code for the sake of the question, but I want to show it in its entirety. Ignore if you can, where I get the table name from a text box in a form. I know this part works. My issue is with the Update Query

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub btnInsertClosestCityRegion_Click()
Dim strSQL As Variant
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim tblnewbid As String
Dim Distance As Integer


Set db = CurrentDb

tblnewbid = FSO.GetBaseName(Me.txtFileName)
Debug.Print tblnewbid

db.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & tblnewbid & " ADD COLUMN O_CityRegion CHAR", dbFailOnError
db.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & tblnewbid & " ADD COLUMN D_CityRegion CHAR", dbFailOnError

Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Select [Origin] FROM " & tblnewbid & " ; ")


rs1.MoveFirst

    strSQL = "UPDATE " & tblnewbid & " INNER JOIN [tblDistanceCalc]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " ON [tblDistanceCalc].[Origin] = " & tblnewbid & ".[Origin]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " SET " & tblnewbid & ".[O_CityRegion]=[tblDistanceCalc].[Region] WHERE tblDistanceCalc.Distance = (SELECT DMIN(Distance) FROM tblDistanceCalc)"


    db.Execute (strSQL), dbFailOnError


rs1.Close

Set rs1 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

DoCmd.Hourglass False
MsgBox "The proxity of the city within the states have been added!"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm confused about the recordset - it's not being referenced anywhere in your update statement - Why are you opening it?.
I'm also pretty certain you can't use aggregate functions in sub queries like that in access. This thread might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375207/how-do-i-perform-update-query-with-subquery-in-access

Comment: It was left over from another bit of code that worked for me that did a similar function. This one, however, I am trying to use an aggregate function and update a table. This is possible by using a subroutine. Some mixture of Update and Select statement will allow this to work, but I can't figure it out. If you ignore the recordset, can you think of a way to make it work? Thanks!