# SQL Query to MS SQL - Parameter Value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Trying to run this SQL query in MS Access but it keeps asking for parameter value. I am new to MS Access. Can you please help me with the query ?

```
    UPDATE AC_E2 a  
        SET 
  a.EXPRESSION = (Select "No : " & NO & " CAT : " & CAT from AC_E1 f WHERE a.NUM = f.NUM)   
        WHERE 
      a.PROPNUM = (Select PROPNUM from AC_E2 e WHERE e.EXPRESSION LIKE "No: @M.NO  CAT: @M.CAT" and e.NUM = a.NUM)
```

I am just trying to search a column in table `AC_E2` which has this expression: `No: @M.NO CAT: @M.CAT` and am trying to replace the `@M.NO` and `@M.CAT` with their respective value from `AC_E1` table.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: @JohnConde I think you may have missed the edit there. It looks like he's using Access, not SQL Server.

Comment: @JohnConde , I have removed tags. In MSaccess I am using SQLView to write query and I guess my query is more written in SQL formatting and I am looking for something to run in MSAccess. Was wondering if my question wasn't making it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got hint from this link and changed my query accordingly:
[How do I perform update query with subquery in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375207/how-do-i-perform-update-query-with-subquery-in-access)

```
UPDATE AC_E2 a, AC_E1 b
SET a.EXPRESSION = "No : " & b.NO & " CAT : " & b.CAT
WHERE 
a.NUM = e.NUM AND
a.EXPRESSION = 'No: @M.NO  CAT: @M.CAT'
```

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access queries, the square brackets are a convention to prompt the user running the query to input a parameter.  e.g. [EXPRESSION] will prompt the user to enter the value named, "EXPRESSION".

Comment: Even the query without square brackets doesn't run. I have removed it in my question too.