# Outputting the result of an SQL query into a text box

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, dlookup

I'm creating a form that displays information about an individual that is taken from two tables when a name is entered by the user. I want the fields to be output into they're own text boxes. My code looks similar to what's below.

When I run the code it displays the literal query "SELECT name etc..." in the textbox.  I saw Dlookup works for textboxes but to my understanding it doesn't work well with more than one table. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

PS I'm a VBA/access newbie

```
Dim SQL, SearchInput As String

SQL = "SELECT name" & _
      "FROM tablename INNER JOIN othertablename ON tablename.name = othertablename.name" & _
      "WHERE  tablename.name LIKE ""*" & SearchInput & "*""

Me.txtbox = SQL
```

Comment: You are assigning your string to txtbox, that's why you see it there. You need to execute your statement and assign that result to the txtbox.

Comment: Are you searching for existing record or are you creating a new record? If this is search for existing then either apply filter criteria or go to record. If this is a new record, select name in a multi-column combobox then expressions in textboxes reference columns of combobox. No VBA, no DLookup for the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but it's faster to answer than hunt for the other posts.

You need to declare a recordset and assign the data returned from the select statement to it. This will leave you with something very similar to an array. After that you need to just line up the array element to the positions of the columns. IE. rs(0)=name in the select statement above.

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim SQL As String, SearchInput As String
SQL = "SELECT name " & _
  "FROM tablename INNER JOIN othertablename ON tablename.name = othertablename.name " & _
  "WHERE tablename.name LIKE ""*" & SearchInput & "*""
   Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

Me.txtBox = rs(0)
```

That should work.

Comment: That is the basics, but you might get more than one result, esp with undefined search like the one in the question, so should ideally check that.

Comment: How about rs.Close and Set rs = Nothing? And It is better to check rs.Recordcount because if there is no records returned you will get an error in "rs(0)"

Comment: These are both good points, however not asked in the question so I didn't mention them. Also much like the question, I'm entirely positive that this information is widely available with a 5 second search.

Comment: A simple check for`Not rs.EOF`is sufficent as if there is at least one record if true after opening the rs. Or use`on Error Resume Next`in front of`rs(0)`and handle no resuilt, by checking `Err.Nr`<> 0.

Comment: And use parameters like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56667682/9439330 (e.g try a double-quote in SearchInput to raise an error). ALso eacj line of sql string should start or end with a blank (try MsgBox SQL)!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to MS Access & VBA in general, I'll propose a solution which avoids VBA entirely.

---

In your current code, I assume that `SearchInput` is sourcing its value from another control on your form.

I would suggest creating a new saved query (called it `MyQuery`) with the following SQL:

```
select table2.name from table1 inner join table2 on table1.name = table2.name
```

Then, in the Control Source for your textbox, use a `DLookup` expression with the following arguments:

```
=dlookup("[name]", "MyQuery", "table1.name like '*" & [SearchInput] & "*'")
```

Here, `[SearchInput]` refers to the name of the control on your form containing the search criteria.